Refinement of IMU sensor-to-segment calibration for the shin algorithm
I'm currently working on a project that seeks to integrate IMU motion capture system to deliver a vibrotactile feedback through vibration motors. The project is focused in runners, and it could either be used for performance enhancement or injury prevention. Right now, i'm focused on the implementation of the IMU to gather the necessary parameters, which in this case is tibial acceleration. I've been working on the algorithm to do the sensor-to-segment calibration, and I already got some results which I'm not really sure how reliable they are. I was hoping that someone could give me any piece of advice or tell me if I'm missing something important.
Some relevant information:

The sensors i'm using are the Movella Dot, which already give you the sensor orientation using kalman filter.

I'm placing the sensor in the medial anterior part of the shin (the boney part).

So far I'm implementing a static and functional calibration. Where the static is a short recording standing upright, and the functional is a recording walking slow. With the static calibration I get the vertical axis measuring the gravitational vector. From the functional calibration I get the anterio-posterior axis using principal component analysis of the acceleration recording. Finally I just correct the axes to ensure orthogonality and compute the y axis as the cross product, normalize and finally get the transformation matrix.


This is what I have so far:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Butterworth filter
def filtering(fs, cutoff, data):
    order = 2
    b, a = signal.butter(order, (2 * cutoff / fs), btype='low')
    filt_data = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=0)
    return filt_data

# Extract accelerometer, gyroscope, and quaternion data
def get_data(filename):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',', header=0)

    acc_data = data[['Acc_X', 'Acc_Y', 'Acc_Z']].values / 9.81  # Convert to m/s^2
    gyr_data = data[['Gyr_X', 'Gyr_Y', 'Gyr_Z']].values * (np.pi / 180)  # Convert to rad/s
    quaternions = data[['Quat_W', 'Quat_X', 'Quat_Y', 'Quat_Z']].values

    return acc_data, gyr_data, quaternions

# Rotate vector using quaternion
def rotate_vector(quaternion, vector):
    r = R.from_quat(quaternion)  # Quaternion (w, x, y, z)
    rotated_vector = r.apply(vector)
    return rotated_vector

# Static calibration: Z-axis alignment (NOT NORMALIZED)
def static_calibration(filename):
    [acc_data, gyr_data, quaternions] = get_data(filename)

    fs = 120  # Sampling frequency
    N = len(acc_data)

    # Rotate accelerometer data to global frame using quaternions
    a_global = np.zeros((N, 3))
    for i in range(120, N-1):
        q = quaternions[i]  # Get quaternion for this sample
        a_global[i, :] = rotate_vector(q, acc_data[i, :])  # Rotate using quaternion

    # Filter the rotated accelerometer data
    a_global_filtered = filtering(fs, 15, a_global)

    # Estimate gravity vector during the static upright position
    Tstart, Tend = 0, N  # Replace with actual indices for static period
    gravity_vector = np.mean(a_global_filtered[Tstart:Tend, :], axis=0)
    gravity_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(gravity_vector)
    sensor_z_axis = gravity_vector

    return sensor_z_axis, a_global_filtered, gyr_data

# Functional calibration: Rotate raw data and apply PCA to define X-axis (NOT NORMALIZED)
def functional_calibration(filename):
    [acc_data,_, quaternions] = get_data(filename)

    fs = 120
    N = len(acc_data)

    # Rotate accelerometer data to global frame using quaternions
    a_global = np.zeros((N, 3))
    for i in range(120, N-1):
        q = quaternions[i]  # Get quaternion for this sample
        a_global[i, :] = rotate_vector(q, acc_data[i, :])  # Rotate using quaternion

    # Filter the rotated accelerometer data
    a_global_filtered = filtering(fs, 15, a_global)

    # Now apply PCA to rotated accelerometer data to define the X-axis
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    a_global_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(a_global_filtered)

    pca = PCA(n_components=1)
    pca.fit(a_global_scaled)
    sensor_x_axis = pca.components_[0]
    #sensor_x_axis /= np.linalg.norm(sensor_x_axis)  # Normalize

    return sensor_x_axis, a_global_filtered

# Compute Y-axis to ensure orthogonality and right-handed system
def gram_schmidt(sensor_x_axis, sensor_z_axis):
    # Apply Gram-Schmidt process to get orthogonal vectors
    sensor_x_axis_corrected = sensor_x_axis - (np.dot(sensor_x_axis, sensor_z_axis)/np.dot(sensor_z_axis, sensor_z_axis)) * sensor_z_axis
    
    # Compute Y-axis as cross product of Z and X to enforce right-handed system
    sensor_y_axis = np.cross(sensor_x_axis_corrected, sensor_z_axis)
    
    # Get orthonormal vectors by normalizing
    sensor_x_axis_norm = sensor_x_axis_corrected / np.linalg.norm(sensor_x_axis_corrected) 
    sensor_y_axis_norm = sensor_y_axis / np.linalg.norm(sensor_y_axis)
    sensor_z_axis_norm = sensor_z_axis / np.linalg.norm(sensor_z_axis)
    
    return sensor_x_axis_norm, sensor_y_axis_norm, sensor_z_axis_norm

# Combine axes into transformation matrix and align data
def apply_transformation(a_global_filtered, gyr_data, transformation_matrix):
    aligned_acc = np.dot(a_global_filtered, transformation_matrix.T)
    aligned_gyr = np.dot(gyr_data, transformation_matrix.T)
    return aligned_acc, aligned_gyr

# Main function to align data
def align_tibia_data(static_file, functional_file):
    sensor_z_axis, static_acc, gyr_data = static_calibration(static_file) # Z-axis normalized
    sensor_x_axis, functional_acc = functional_calibration(functional_file)
    tibia_x_axis_norm, tibia_y_axis_norm, tibia_z_axis_norm = gram_schmidt(sensor_x_axis, sensor_z_axis)

    print(f"X & Z: {np.dot(tibia_z_axis_norm, tibia_x_axis_norm)}\nX & Y: {np.dot(tibia_y_axis_norm, tibia_x_axis_norm)}\nZ % Y: {np.dot(tibia_y_axis_norm, tibia_z_axis_norm)}")
    # Transformation matrix
    transformation_matrix = np.vstack([tibia_x_axis_norm, tibia_y_axis_norm, tibia_z_axis_norm])

    # Align accelerometer and gyroscope data
    aligned_acc, aligned_gyr = apply_transformation(functional_acc, gyr_data, transformation_matrix)

    plot_acceleration(functional_acc, aligned_acc)
    
    return aligned_acc, aligned_gyr, transformation_matrix


def plot_acceleration(a_global, aligned_acc, fs = 120):
    time = np.arange(len(a_global)) / fs

    # Plot raw vs aligned acceleration
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 8))

    for i, axis in enumerate(['X', 'Y', 'Z']):
        axs[i].plot(time, a_global[:, i], label=f'Raw {axis}')
        axs[i].plot(time, aligned_acc[:, i], label=f'Aligned {axis}')
        axs[i].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        axs[i].set_ylabel(f'Acceleration {axis} (m/s^2)')
        axs[i].legend()
        axs[i].grid(True)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


# Calculate and plot PTA (Peak Tibial Acceleration) over time
def plot_pta(aligned_tibia_acc, fs=120):
    # Calculate time array
    time = np.arange(len(aligned_tibia_acc)) / fs
    
    # Compute PTA (norm of each acceleration vector at each time step)
    pta = np.linalg.norm(aligned_tibia_acc, axis=1)
    
    # Plot PTA over time
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(time, pta, label='PTA (m/s^2)', color='b')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('PTA (m/s^2)')
    plt.title('Peak Tibial Acceleration Over Time')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    
    return pta

# Main execution
static_calibration_file = r"\test 16-10\standing still upright.csv"
functional_calibration_file = r"\test 16-10\walking slow calibration.csv"
aligned_acc, _, transformation_matrix = align_tibia_data(static_calibration_file, functional_calibration_file)

test_data_file = r"\test 16-10\test data.csv"
acc_data, _, quaternions = get_data(test_data_file)
global_acc = np.array([rotate_vector(q, acc) for q, acc in zip(quaternions, acc_data)])  # Apply quaternion rotation
global_filtered_acc = filtering(120, 15, global_acc)

# Align the test data to the tibial reference frame
aligned_tibia_acc = np.dot(global_filtered_acc, transformation_matrix.T) - [0, 0, 9.81]

# Plot tibial acceleration over time
tibial_acceleration = plot_pta(aligned_tibia_acc)

